# Intersect 2 lines at the same ratio through a point

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have a small geometric problem and I am searching for a exact solution.
As its a geometric problem I think its best ilustrated as a picture.

[image: Problem]

I have given A, B, C, D and P. These are on a 2D coordinate system with float accuracy.
I want to find a line, that intersects both lines at the same ratio and goes through point P. 
ultimately I want calculate the ratio that is marked in blue in the description picture and I want to be exact. I could only find approximations so far.
I starting to think, that there isnt even a exact solution to this problem...

I hope I described my problem as exact as possible and there is a math genius out there that can help me. I am just a stupid programmer ;-(

Kind regards,
Dominik

Comment: Please split the new problem into a separate question.

Comment: sorry about that.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we call the unknown ratio (that is, $30\%$ in your diagram) $t$. Then we have these expressions for $L$ and $K$:

$$ L = \begin{pmatrix} x_A+t(x_B-x_A) \\ y_A+t(y_B-y_A) \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
K = \begin{pmatrix} x_C+t(x_D-x_C) \\ y_C+t(y_D-y_C) \end{pmatrix} $$

and these expressions for the vectors $\vec{PL}$ and $\vec{PK}$:

$$  \tag{1}
\vec{PL} = \begin{pmatrix} x_A+t(x_B-x_A)-x_P \\ y_A+t(y_B-y_A) -y_P \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\vec{PK} = \begin{pmatrix} x_C+t(x_D-x_C)-x_P \\ y_C+t(y_D-y_C)-y_P \end{pmatrix} $$

We want to find $t$ such that $\vec{PL}$ and $\vec{PK}$ are *parallel*. There is a nifty condition for 2D vectors being parallel, namely that we must have
$$ \tag{2} x_{PL}\cdot y_{PK} = x_{PK}\cdot y_{PL} $$
If you insert the coordinates of $\vec{PL}$ and $\vec{PK}$ from (1) into (2), it simplifies into a *quadratic equation* in $t$, which you can solve using the quadratic formula. In general there may be either zero, one, or two solutions in the interval between $0$ and $1$. (Or in some degenerate cases, *every* $t$ may work, such as for $A(0,2), B(2,2), C(2,0), D(0,0), P(1,1)$).

Can you handle the algebra yourself from here?

Comment: Thanks for the really quick and good solution.
I updated my question to the underlying problem I originally wanted to solve with the solution to the problem.
That there might be more then one or zero solutions might be an indicator that I have to approximate mine :-(